# What is the Halacha of establishing one's home at the onset of Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, vehicles-transportation, contemporary-halacha, erev-shabbat

If one cannot make it home, I heard there's a din that one sets his place where they are now upto 2000 amot. What's the source of this? What if I'm in the back of a car?

Answer (score 1):

This is passim in *mishnayos maseches Eruvin*, indeed it's the fundamental idea in that *maseches*<sup>[1]</sup>: that one has, on *Shabas* (or *yom tov*), 2000 *amos* to walk in around where he started *Shabas*. If he started in a city, he has the entire city plus 2000 *amos*. See details there.

---

<sup>[1] Well, in the part of it that deals with *eruve t'chumin*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you're referring to the [Mishna in Eruvin 4:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Eruvin.4.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)

> מִי שֶׁבָּא בַדֶּרֶךְ וְחָשְׁכָה לוֹ, וְהָיָה מַכִּיר אִילָן אוֹ גָדֵר, וְאָמַר, שְׁבִיתָתִי תַחְתָּיו, לֹא אָמַר כְּלוּם. שְׁבִיתָתִי בְעִקָּרוֹ, מְהַלֵּךְ מִמְּקוֹם רַגְלָיו וְעַד עִקָּרוֹ אַלְפַּיִם אַמָּה, וּמֵעִקָּרוֹ וְעַד בֵּיתוֹ אַלְפַּיִם אַמָּה. נִמְצָא מְהַלֵּךְ מִשֶּׁחֲשֵׁכָה אַרְבַּעַת אֲלָפִים אַמָּה:
>
> One who was on a journey and it became dark, and he recognized a tree or a fence and said, “Let my Shabbat place be under it”, he has said nothing. If he said, “Let my Shabbat place be at its root”, he may walk from the place where he stands to its root a distance of two thousand cubits, and from its root to his house another two thousand cubits. Thus he can walk four thousand cubits after dusk.

Not sure what the car has to do with Eruvin - unless you're asking if 2,000 Amot is time or distance; in Eruvin it's distance. (as opposed to Tefilat HaDerech and Matza baking where maybe the "distances" refer to time, based on how long it takes to walk that distance.)

Comment: That's pretty much what I was asking. The situation that I was worried about is if I was in the back of a car trying to drive within city limits before the onset of Shabbos and the time elapsed and the driver wouldn't let me out to designate a root. That's why I was trying to see what the shulchan aruch and other poskim say on this mishneh so I can get a fuller idea of the parameters here.

Comment: @KfirShlomo - then maybe that should be edited into the question? we can't read your mind...

Comment: @kfir people can only answer the question you write down. If you wanted the answer to a different question, don't write this one.